# Are shopping questions on-topic?

Tags: support

I'm wanting some clarification on whether the following questions are on-topic:

- What are some good places to buy *x*?
- What is the cheapest place to buy *x*?
- Is *x* a good place to shop at? (for determining whether certain websites are trustworthy)
- Is *x* a good place to buy *y*? (for determining whether certain websites are trustworthy/reliable for a given piece of hardware)

I've tried to search Meta for some answer to this, but there's no question that specifically asks it, even if some answers seem to suggest that it is the case, and I wanted to clarify.

Comment: [Here](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/542/60) is a related Meta question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no.

"What are some good places to buy *x*?" is both a list question and opinion-based.  Neither type of question does very well on StackExchange; a question that combines the two would do extremely poorly.

"What is the cheapest place to buy *x*?" is subject to change without notice, and any answer could well be incorrect by the time the author presses the "Post" button.

"Is *x* a good place to shop at?" and "Is *x* a good place to buy *y*?" are opinion-based; the corresponding "Is *x* engaged in deceptive business practices?" is off-topic for this site.